# How to open two html pages whenever I run Node JS server?

Tags: node.js

```
app.get('', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/api.html"))
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/j.html"))
})
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1 style='color:red'>Error404</h1><p>Page Not Found</p>")
})

//Running Server On Port 4000
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("port running on 4000")
});
```

1. Whenevr I am running Node JS I am displaying api.html in browser
2. I would like to display another webpage(j.html) right after api.html
3. Whenever I call same Node JS server
4. Is it possible to display 2 web pages?

Comment: What do you mean by "display 2 web pages"? How would that look like?

Comment: one html page in one tab another html page in another tab

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send two HTML pages for a single request. Because for a single request there is a single response and your response here is an HTML file.

To load another page in another tab, you have to explicitly make a new request for the second HTML (`j.html`) from the javascript of your first page (`api.html`) using `window.open('http://localhost:4000/j.html');`

You NodeJs code will look something like this:

```
app.get('', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/api.html"))
})
app.get('/j.html', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/j.html"));
})
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1 style='color:red'>Error404</h1><p>Page Not Found</p>")
})

//Running Server On Port 4000
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("port running on 4000")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In api.html you could open a new with only frontend code.

```
<script>
    window.open("https://stackoverflow.com")
</script>
```

So you could send the script-tag in html directly as well (icky).

```
res.send(`
<script>
    window.open("https://stackoverflow.com")
</script>
`)
```

Browsers also doesn't react well to this kind of spammy popup-tabs. In your case whitelisting might be an option. But otherwise you need to trigger the open on a user interaction (such as clicking a button), but I believe that belongs to a different question.